# How do I escape a backslash in LESS?

Tags: css, less

I'm having some issues escaping a backslash in LESS. Here's my code:

```
&.room {
    &:after {
        content:"\";
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: use double(\\) instead of a single one(\)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
&.room {
    &:after {
        content:"\\";
    }
}
```

Comment: so there can be a class with the name of & in css?

Comment: @Hushme no that means when the current element has that class

Comment: No problem. You can have a & because this is LESS not CSS.

Comment: it ends up like `element.room`

Comment: The above does not work. Although it compiles, it produces abnormalities in the output which you may or may not come across straight away. It was only when I added additional code some time later that it broke - so be aware!

Comment: The question is about escaping a backslash, I am not sure how it can produce abnormalities. Could you expand on how it breaks it?

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this issue, Escaping quotes keeps the escape backslash in

```
content: ~"\"";
```

**produces**

```
content: \";
```

Can refer to the official repository of `less`. [ISSUES](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1142)

OR as **@SLC** mentioned, can use double backslash.